# SQL - SELECT with inner IF or CASE

Tags: sql, postgresql, if-statement, select

Trying to have a row that will display 'YES' or 'NO' depending on values found (if a tree has been treated before the date given in argument say YES else NO).

Here's my function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION tree_care(care_date DATE)
RETURNS TABLE(name VARCHAR(32), type VARCHAR(32), treated TEXT) AS
$$
BEGIN
RETURN QUERY
SELECT tree.name,
       tree.type,
       IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM treatment
                  JOIN tree ON tree.name = treatment.tree_name
                  WHERE treatment.date < care_date) THEN
            'YES'::text
       ELSE
            'NO'::text
       END IF
FROM tree;
END;
$$
```

And I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "EXISTS"
LINE 8:            IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM treatment
```

How does one implement an IF statement inside a SELECT?

*PS: Using postgresql 9.4*

Comment: I think you need a semicolon after the END IF to close the IF EXISTS conditional logic you have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IF` is control flow.  Use `CASE` because this is within a `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT tree.name,
       tree.type,
       (CASE WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1
                          FROM treatment
                          WHERE tree.name = treatment.tree_name AND
                                treatment.date < care_date
                         ) THEN
             THEN 'YES'::text
             ELSE 'NO'::text
        END) as Flag
FROM tree;
```

I am also guessing that you intend a correlated subquery, rather than an independent subquery.

Comment: Thanks worked perfectly (with the AND instead of THEN in the WHERE statement and removing double THEN at the end of course). Learning everyday! That's what I get for sticking to IFs :)